# Objective C: Parsing JSON string

Tags: objective-c, json, parsing

I have a string data which I need to parse into a dictionary object. Here is my code:

```
NSString *barcode = [NSString stringWithString:@"{\"OTP\": 24923313, \"Person\": 100000000000112, \"Coupons\":  [ 54900012445, 499030000003, 00000005662 ] }"];
NSLog(@"%@",[barcode objectFromJSONString]);
```

In this log, I get NULL result. But if I pass only one value in Coupons, I get the results. How to get all three values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cyrille is right, here is the autoritative answer:

[The application/json Media Type for JavaScript Object Notation (JSON): 2.4 Numbers](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.4)

> The representation of numbers is similar to that used in most programming languages.  A number contains an integer component that may be prefixed with an optional minus sign, which may be followed by a fraction part and/or an exponent part.
>
> Octal and hex forms are not allowed.  **Leading zeros are not allowed.**

Answer (score 1):

00000005662 might not be a proper integer number as it's prefixed by zeroes (which means it's octal, IIRC). Try removing them.

Comment: That actually does seem to be the issue, when trying to get the error form the JSON parser. +1 to you, good sir.

Comment: I love being called "Good sir". Makes me think I'm an English lord. :)